# add li and ul tags dynamically in php

Tags: php, dynamic-list

I want to write a code that a user can make a menue dynamically and easily, the way they want with submenues and ...
one of my code's part is to make li and ul tags dynamically.
there is a ul with one li and the user is going to add more to it with two checkboxes.
on of them is on the right side of the li , and another is in botton. if the user checked the right one it means that they want to make a ul for that li
( and just like I said the added li should have two checkboxes too) and when choosing bottom one it will add another li to the li (they are in a unique ul tag )
and the user can add as much as needed for any part. but I don't know how to add these until the user clicks on a cancel botton. 
I am new to php, and I have stuck in this part for days!
the code is like this:

```
<?php
echo  "<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"box4\" value=\"cancel\" name=\"cancel\">";
echo"<ul>";
echo"<li>";
echo"<input type=\"checkbox\" size=\"10\" id=\"box1\" name=\"right\">";
echo"</li>";
echo"<input type=\"checkbox\" size=\"10\" id=\"box2\" name=\"bottom\"></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"box3\" value=\"submit\" name=\"submit\">";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST[$submit]) 
if(isset($_POST[$right])
dynamically create a ul (and a li in it with two checkboxes) for that li
if(isset ($_POST[bottom])
dynamically add a li with two chekboxes for that ul, under that existing li
?>
```

Comment: To manipulate the DOM use http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

While any javascript tree plugin with checkbox support should work. [jquery-tree](https://github.com/daredevel/jquery-tree). It can generate tree structure from json or li/ul tree. Of course it required jquery to be included into your page.

Comment: but the problem is I don't know jquery! actually I was going to give a unique id for each of the lis, and save them in an array with 2 numbers : their own id, and the parent id.

Comment: You will need javascript/jquery to open child ul/li tag any how. So checking jquery is not a bad idea. Also their are plain javascript tree plugin available but I did not checkout them yet.

Comment: I will check it to see what I can do for it, and thank you very much.